# Microsoft BotBuilder javascript sample error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to test the Microsoft BotBUilder samples with the Bot Framework Emulator.
 I have cloned the BotBuilder [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/02.echo-bot) and gone through the readme instructions `npm install` but when I run `npm start` I get this error

```
/home/ronald/Desktop/botbuilder-samples/samples/javascript_nodejs/02.echo-bot/node_modules/csv-parse/lib/index.js:20
    super({...{readableObjectMode: true}, ...opts})
           ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ronald/Desktop/botbuilder-samples/samples/javascript_nodejs/02.echo-bot/node_modules/csv/lib/index.js:6:10)

npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-72-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v7.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! echobot@1.0.0 start: `node ./index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the echobot@1.0.0 start script 'node ./index.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the echobot package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./index.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs echobot
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls echobot
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: what's your `node --version` result ? Look like JS don't understand deconstructing `...`

Comment: Because this works fine: `let opts = {foo:'bar'}; console.log({...{readableObjectMode: true}, ...opts});` > `{readableObjectMode: true, foo: "bar"}`

Comment: node --version gives me v7.10.1

Comment: Posted as answer: BotBuilder need 10.14+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your running it on Nodejs version 7+ and [BotBuilder require 10.14+](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/02.echo-bot#prerequisites).

So your node is not able to understand deconstructing operator `...`.

Try to upgrade your node and it'll works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try:

```
super({readableObjectMode: true, ...opts})
```

I don't think you need to spread the first object.

Comment: I get the same error.     ```super({{readableObjectMode: true}, ...opts})
           ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Comment: The code you pasted back to me, isn't the code I sent you as an example. You've added a {} around the readableObjectMode ? Remove it so its just this: super({readableObjectMode: true, ...opts}) which is what  I sent to you in the answer :)

Comment: Whoops you're right, I've still got the error though ```    super({ readableObjectMode: true, ...opts })
                                      ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

Comment: Please read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - If you could provide us your code, we'll have a much better chance of helping you

Comment: I have added a link to the repo I am using :) Thankyou!

Comment: It's not the best way to do it but it should works fine.